# How install in local maven repo a sub-project via gradle (in a function)?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, groovy, gradlew

In gradle, when running my script, I have a bunch of sub-projects that are dependent on others. We need to pull them in as external jars (not `compile project` for various reasons). So I need them installed locally. I want this to be a function defined in the parent gradle.

When I try to call `install ":projName"` inside a function, I get the error:

> Could not find method install() for arguments [:projName] on root project 'test' of type org.gradle.api.Project

How would I do this?

```
ext.installLocal = {moduleName ->

    //...elided... doing some checking, conditionals, etc

    //Try to install locally
    install ":${moduleName}"
}
```

Comment: Where did you get `install` from?  I believe you want the `publishToMavenLocal` task from the [Maven plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html).  But this kind of sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) - why do you "need to pull them in as external jars"?  (Note that either way, Gradle will just end up putting the relevant Jars on your classpath).

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I get `"Could not find method publishToMavenLocal() for arguments [:projName] on root project 'test' of type org.gradle.api.Project"`. It's the same issue. How do I call that task from inside my method?

Comment: You can't "call" tasks.  Tasks in gradle form a dependency graph - i.e. your task depends on some other task in some way.  I believe what you're trying to achieve is going to be pretty tricky in Gradle - what's the need to include local publishing as part of the flow?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth The need is for testing purposes. We have another sub-project that tests using these other apps and it needs to pull them in as external dependencies so we can test it 100% as they'd be used in prod.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `build.finalizedBy(publishToMavenLocal)` command to all your subprojects `build.gradle` file that need to be pushed in your maven local. If your need to push all your subprojects to maven local, you can call this command in `subprojects{ }` closure in main `build.gradle` file. But remember if subprojects are dependent on each other their build order is critical.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. But won't the build order be enforced by the compile dependencies and including the finalized by in each gradle? Or do I still need to hard code the order?

Comment: If some project needs the other projects from your `.m2` folder then build order could be important. But, if default order works then there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: So I have the following: `module-tester` has a dependency on `module-one` which has a dependency on `module-two`. So I need `module-two` installed in local maven prior to installing `module-one` which needs to happen prior to running `module-tester`. Will it work if I just put `build.finalizedBy(publishToMavenLocal)` in each of these? Or do I need to do something more than that?

Comment: Yes that should work. You define your repositories right. Gradle also needs to know that it should look at the local maven repository. `repositories {
  mavenLocal()
}` like this in your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. when i do `./gradlew clean build` it does them in random order and it fails because it does module one first and that fails without module two being built and installed. how do i make it build module two when module one's dependency on it is found?

Comment: You need to add module-tester build.gradle to `dependencies{
    compile project(':module-one')
}` and you need to add module-one build.gradle to `dependencies{
    compile project(':module-two')
}` . This will make the order. I thought you made this already sorry.

Comment: These commands will create an execution order for your project, firstly module two then module one and finally tester

Comment: if i include them via `compile project ()` then they don't use the installed jar for the dependency. and i want them to use the jar from local Maven, not do an internal project inclusion

Comment: Could you share your gradle files

Comment: I won't be able to share them until friday, but I will post them here then. Thank you for helping!

Comment: FYI: the `build.finalizedBy(publishToMavenLocal)` does not fully work as it's different from the install task. It does not do dependencies, and the POM created is missing those dependencies.